# Alternatives to Window Blinds for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, themes, desktop-customization

I would like to reskin Windows 7. I have bought Window Blinds, but I am looking for clean and simplistic Skins, Window Blind Skins are extremely pimped out.

Are there any alternative to Window Blinds?

I guess I really want my Windows 7 install to look as close as possible to Linux Mint. That would be awesome if this was possible.

Thanks

Comment: +1 vote, I'm also interested in this. Window Blinds is not my style, don't like it.

Comment: I agree that most of skins for WB are heavy, but you can also find some lighter ones, depending on the author, like some of [these ones](http://www.wincustomize.com/users/20239/danillooc).

Comment: @Gnoupi, I'm looking for something simplistic that functions correctly, if you know any skins, please share, thank you.

Comment: Also anyone willing to develop a Linux Mint Skin for Window Blinds - I would pay for.

Comment: How much? Give enough and I'll create one. :)

Comment: @Shiki, you can create one with skin studio, publish on winCustomize, sell for $5.00 a piece, lots of people will buy, I'll be first customer.

Comment: Okay. This whole Stardock is a $@#!. Will try solving this with patched uxtheme method.

Comment: @Shiki tried that, the ubuntu skin (human) didn't look all that great on Win7.

Answer (score 1):

create your own skin, use skinstudio.
free version available

Comment: truly this answer is useless to those of us who can't do design!

Answer (score 1):

you can download skins from deviantart, essentially for free

Comment: Tried that also. You have to patch the dlls. Thats ok but still..only VistaVG was somewhat OK as a skin, but had some strange issue.